# Order of Formal Power Series?

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, formal-power-series

Please help me with the Definition of $ord(f)$. (Order of Formal Power Series) 
From my notes from lectuer i have that:

$Ord(f)$ is the largest $i$ such that  $f^\alpha = o$, if $|\alpha| = \alpha_1+...+ \alpha_k < i$.

However in Wikipedia For a non-zero formal Laurent series, the minimal integer  $n$ such that $a_n \neq 0 $  is called the order of f.

And now im confused :\

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to prove that these two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: no, i dont see that they are equivalent :(